# How do I tell JsHint to ignore "unresolved function or method" warnings on objects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jshint

JSHint is complaining on the following line of code:

```
angular.mock.module('main')
```

The complains are that `mock` is is an unresolved variable, and `module` is an unresolved function. I've tried to add them to the globals at the top of my file, but this doesn't work because they are not being referenced as globals, they are being referenced as members of `angular`.

How do I get JSHint to ignore them?

Comment: Did you add `angular` as a global?

Comment: @Knu `angular` is `require`'d in, and `require` is a global

Comment: I mean did you add `/* globals angular */` to your file(s)?

Comment: @Knu Wouldn't it be `global angular: true`? Also, `angular` is just one example, there are others that are not framework specific.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore single line

```
 angular.mock.module('main') // jshint ignore:line
```

Or

```
// Code here won't be ignored by JSHint.
/* jshint ignore:start */
// Code here will be ignored by JSHint.
/* jshint ignore:end */
```

Comment: This is a bit hamfisted... I'de rather be able to tell JSHint that `mock` and `module` really are real things

Comment: @DavidGrinberg yep you are right ^^ I just answered "How do I get JSHint to ignore them?" anyway it could be usefull for someone

Comment: while this isn't the most elegant way to do it, ignoring the lint at some level (line, block, or config) seems to be the only way to do it. I remember something about describing the object, but after an extensive google search I believe that was just for @param comments. If you know the answer, it would make for a nice addition, imho.